# Новая Почта API v. 3.3.1 Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Установил модуль Новой Почты на Opencart 3. В комплекте идут:

```
oc_novaposhta_references.sql

novaposhta_ochelp_sms_notify.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_ajax_quick_checkout.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_cn.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_default_checkout.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_journal_quick_checkout.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_octemplates_fastorder.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_orderpro.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_simple.ocmod.zip
shippingdata_simple_apimain.ocmod.zip

upload
```

Ругается что нет таблицы городов и отделений. Может быть кто-то может поделиться, чтобы я смог нормально обновить базу и все заработало?! Спасибо!

Comment: Вы же добавили в бд магазина таблицы из oc_novaposhta_references.sql ?

Comment: А что ругается? Модуль Новой Почты или Simple? Не проще ли задать вопросы разработчикам: и первый и второй очень активно реагируют на обращения.

Comment: Похоже, что речь идет об этом: http://simpleopencart.com/geo_2018_03.zip